# Whats the smallest de-/normalized number greater than 1?(64bit)

Tags: floating-point, binary, floating-accuracy, ieee-754, denormalization

I am struggeling with denormalized numbers.

I know that:

> Essentially, a denormalized float has the ability to represent the
> SMALLEST (in magnitude) number that is possible to be represented with
> any floating point value.

I also know that numbers can be represented like that:

[image]

However where I am stuck is the actual computation of the de-/normalized number?

Is there a method to do that? Are there any special numbers?

Would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Subnormal” is the term used in the IEEE 754 standard.

There are no subnormal numbers greater than 1; subnormal numbers are small (tinier than the normal numbers).

The minimum normal exponent is -1022 (encoded as the bits 00000000001, since the exponent encoding is biased by 1023). Subnormal numbers have a lower exponent encoding, encoded as all zero bits 00000000000. (Although the encoding is 0, the exponent it represents is the same for encoding 1, −1 1022. The exponent encoding 0 indicates the leading bit of the significand is 0 instead of 1.)

The value of a subnormal number is the significand (fraction part) multiplied by 2<sup>-1022</sup>, with the sign bit applied (0 for positive, 1 for negative). The significand is formed as a leading 0, then the radix point “.”, then the bits of the significand field. So, if the significand field contains 0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101, then the significand value is (in binary) 0.0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101<sub>2</sub>.

If the significand field is completely zero, the value is zero, and the number is generally not considered subnormal. The smallest positive subnormal number has a 1 in its lowest bit and zeros in all other bits. Its value is 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>-1022</sup>, which is 2<sup>-52</sup>•2<sup>-1022</sup> = 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Why is 1 negative, why is 0 positive? I thoughts its actually different? Is this the same for normalized and denormalized numbers?

Comment: @user5414: The sign bit is always 0 for positive and 1 for negative. I do not know the history. It may simply be that integers grew that way (counting from 0 up to some number, then having to use the high bit to indicate negation). In floating point, it is usually expressed by writing the sign’s contribution as -1 raised to the power of the sign bit, which produces +1 for 0 and -1 for 1.

Comment: @user5414 `1` in the sign bit indicates a negative number because it's defined that way - think of it as indicating the presence of a "-" sign... Probably has something to do with the "normal" practice of not using a sign for positive numbers - we don't usually write "+42", but a sign is generally used for a negative number. I don't think there's any significant technical reason for it to have been defined that way, though...

Comment: @twalberg Is this same representation for normalized and denormalized numbers?

Comment: @user5414 The IEEE floating point format uses sign-magnitude representation for the mantissa, which means that the sign bit is a separate entity (unlike integers which are usually twos-complement representations). So the sign bit means the same thing regardless of the mantissa's zero/infinity/normal/subnormal status. As a result, you can actually have -0, which is not bitwise equivalent to +0 (but they do compare equal).

Comment: @twalberg Thank you very much for your answer! So thats actually the biased schehme to represent JUST the exponent? (Do you actually know some reference material about that?)

Comment: @user5414 It should be relatively easy to search for articles or other documents online that provide a good in-depth description of the format (and some that provide more detail than you'd ever care about). You should be able to find the actual standards online as well...

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thx for your answer! Do we always calculate by 2^-1022 or are there several cases for different numbers(like the largest positive)? Are there differences in normalized and denormalized numbers?

Comment: @user5414: In IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, subnormal numbers all use 2**-1022. Normal exponents range from -1022 to 1023.

Comment: I think after the sentence "Subnormal numbers have a lower exponent encoding, encoded as all zero bits 00000000000." one needs to point out that even the "all zero bits" for the exponent is interpreted as 1, as otherwise you incorrectly end up with smallest number 2^(0-1023) instead of the correct 2^(-1022).